# Overriding builtin dygraphs plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, dygraphs

Is there a method for overriding the built in plugins in dygraph?  What I am interested in is tweaking the legend plugin slightly and I don't necessarily want to fork the distribution; the current functionality is excellent and I just want to build on it for my specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could set [`Dygraph.PLUGINS`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/dd74404fac69f23183ff8e540a018ca35bab4f7a/src/dygraph.js#L3549) to be a list that includes your own legend implementation, perhaps one which subclasses `Dygraph.Plugins.Legend`.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to use the [`legendFormatter`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683) option, which exists at `HEAD` but has not been included in a dygraphs release yet.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I actually worked around this by forking your repo as at the time it just seemed more straightforward.  Not a clean solution, but it works.  What I wanted was to expose the graph legend text _even_ when a plot is not visible so that I could have some interactivity (basically use the legend itself to hide or show certain graphs rather than an external box).  I initially tried what you suggested, but it seemed to load the default legend (which, looking at the code, seems expected?).